# urpmi database locked

Tags: linux

When attempting to start `rpmdrake`, I get an error message that the urpmi database is locked, supposedly because it's used by another program. As far as I can tell, this is not the case. How do I know which other program is using it? (I suspect none are...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a futex lock that can't easily be unlocked without a reboot. Reboot the system.

It's essentially a problem with the Linux threading libraries and kernel 2.6, if a process is killed while holding a certain type of lock, it is never freed. I believe it will be fixed in later C libraries / kernels (or already has been).

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the lock files .LOCK and .RPMLOCK from the urpmi dir (probably, /var/lib/urpmi). But make sure it is NOT running while you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which process is holding open a file with `lsof` (literally, list open file).

> `lsof | grep /var/lib/urpmi`

Change the grep search, as required.